Persist global shader parameter
I use Shader.SetGlobalVector  to modify the behaviour of multiple shaders. I added a MenuItem to change these parameters in convenient place.
Everything works fine, except these changes do not survive build and quitting unity.
Findings:

Some people suggest to use PlayerPrefs - not good, will save outside the project, so it cannot be shared.

ScriptableObject - I can do something like
public class ShaderParameters : ScriptableObject
{

    [SerializeField]  // trying to show in the inspector
    Vector4 _DistortVector = Vector4.zero; 

    public Vector4 DistortVector // will not show in the inspector
    {
        get
        {
            Debug.Log("read");
            return _DistortVector;
        }
        set
        {
            Debug.Log(value); 
            _DistortVector = value;

            Shader.SetGlobalVector("_DistortVector", value);
        }
    }
}

But I cannot serialize this, only the backing field (no getter/setter). This seems odd because I need only one "thing", but I can create multiple "things/instances" of ScriptableObject
I found that I can do:
[field: SerializeField] public 
int Value { get; private set; } 

But this this seems to only work with auto-implemented properties.

Iterate all materials and apply "local" shader property, which defeats the initial idea...


In the end, I need a way to modify shader parameters/keywords in the editor so that they persist.

We can adapt the example shown in the Unity documentation here to get something that should work for your use case.
This still has the slight quirk that two instances of the ScriptableObject are possible, but we make it so that will only happen if you really try. The [MenuItem] functions that manipulate the persistent data will only ever create one standard instance, and there's no context menu to create a new one, so the only way to get copies would be to manually duplicate the instance or copy the .asset file - and we print useful error messages if we detect that has happened.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

// No CreateAssetMenu attribute, so we don't accidentally create two instances.
// Only our [MenuItem] commands will create an instance via GetInstance()
// and they'll do so if and only if we don't already have an instance.
// (Note I'm not using ScriptableSingleton because that's in the UnityEditor
//  namespace, while we need this to work in both editor AND compiled builds)
public class PersistentSettings : ScriptableObject {

    static PersistentSettings _instance;

    // Do our string lookup just once at start-up.
    // Cache an integer ID to speed up future accesses.
    // (Only important if you set this property frequently)
    static int _distortId = Shader.PropertyToID("_DistortVector");
    static int DistortId => _distortId;

    // Create or get the singleton instance.
    public static PersistentSettings GetInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
            // Check if we already created an asset.
            var path = "Assets/Settings/PersistentSettings.asset";
            _instance = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<PersistentSettings>(path);

            // If not, create it.
            if (_instance == null) {
                _instance = CreateInstance<PersistentSettings>();

                // Save it in a standardized location where we'll look for it.
                if (!UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.IsValidFolder("Assets/Settings"))
                    UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.CreateFolder("Assets", "Settings");
                UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(_instance, path);

                // Add it to preloadedAssets so it's always included in build
                // and initializes itself on start-up.
                var preloadedAssets = new List<Object>(UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.GetPreloadedAssets())
                {
                    _instance
                };
                UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.SetPreloadedAssets(preloadedAssets.ToArray());
            }
        #else
            Debug.LogError("No PersistentSettings created at edit time. Creating a temporary default.");
            _instance = CreateInstance<PersistentSettings>();
        #endif        
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    // Example menu item that gets/creates a PersistentSettings instance and modifies it.
    [UnityEditor.MenuItem("Persistent Settings/Reset Distortion Vector")]
    public static void ZeroDistortion() {
        GetInstance().DistortVector = Vector4.zero;
    }
    #endif

    // TODO: You may want to serialize the "default / at-startup"
    // value separately, so if you change it at runtime, you don't
    // inadvertently change the start-up state of the next build.
    [SerializeField] Vector4 _distortVector;
    public Vector4 DistortVector {
        get => _distortVector;
        set {
            _distortVector = value;
            OnValidate();
        }
    }

    // Apply global properties on start-up /
    // when changed in the inspector.
    void OnValidate() {
        Debug.Log($"Setting distortion vector to {_distortVector}");
        Shader.SetGlobalVector(_distortId, _distortVector);
    }

    // Since we added this asset to the PreloadedAssets array,
    // it gets loaded and OnEnable gets called automatically 
    // when the game boots, even if it's not referenced otherwise.
    void OnEnable() {
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        // If we somehow accidentally created two instances, warn about that!
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this) {
            Debug.LogError("Two PersistentSettings assets exist\n" 
            + UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(_instance) + "\n"
            + UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(this));
        }
    #else
        // OnValidate is called automatically in editor/play mode,
        // so we only need to call it manually in a compiled build.
        OnValidate();
    #endif
        
        _instance = this;
    }
}


Found some strange behaviour. OnEnable will not get called until i either click on PersistSettings.asset or open editor menuItem.
After that OnEnable will get a call on play/stop automatically.

That's expected: Unity won't load it until it knows it's needed. The first call to GetInstance will load it.

PreloadAssets will not load in the editor.
Here is a script which will make it work in Editor also.
using UnityEditor;


[InitializeOnLoad]
public class TouchPreloadedAssets
{
    static TouchPreloadedAssets()
    {
        GetPreloadedAssets();
    }

    private static UnityEngine.Object[] GetPreloadedAssets()
    {
#if UNITY_2018_2_OR_NEWER
        return PlayerSettings.GetPreloadedAssets();
#else
        var findProperty = typeof(PlayerSettings).GetMethod("FindProperty",
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        var preloadedAssetsProp = findProperty.Invoke(null,
                new object[] { "preloadedAssets" }) as SerializedProperty;
        var assets = new UnityEngine.Object[preloadedAssetsProp.arraySize];
        for (int i = assets.Length; --i >= 0;)
        {
            var assetProp = preloadedAssetsProp.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
            // Property access forces Unity Editor to load asset
            assets[i] = assetProp.objectReferenceValue;
        }
        return assets;
#endif
    }
}

